# Postgresql data type for column annotated with `@CreatedDate` `@LastModifiedDate`

Tags: spring, postgresql, annotations, spring-data

I have a postgresql database and I need to choose a data type.

What should be the postgresql data type for column annotated with `@CreatedDate` `@LastModifiedDate` ?

Answer (score -1):

Use `TIMESTAMPTZ` to avoid nightmares with time zone handling.

Don't use `TIMESTAMP`. If you do all your data will have an implicit time zone associated with it. Things will mostly work unless you make the mistake of running your client and server with different time zone settings, or worse, run one of them in a time zone with seasonal changes.

You won't need to do any extra work on your client - the postgres jdbc driver always sends timestamps time zone info attached; it's just ignored by the server if the type is `TIMESTAMP`. There's no extra storage either - both types are stored as an offset from **2000-01-01 00:00:00Z**.

Comment: What about just timestamp? So there is even less nightmare ?

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` requires careful management of client and server time zones. I've added some explanation to my answer.